# iedit: replace from line to the end down

Tags: iedit

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1, package iedit

Suppose I has text:

1.aaa_1111_hello

2.aaa_2222_hello

3.aaa_1111_hello

4.aaa_4444_hello

5.aaa_1111_hello

6.aaa_5555_hello

7.aaa_1111_hello

8.aaa_1111_hello

...

100.aaa_1111_hello

I want to replace all (100 lines) "_1111" by text "_zero"

Steps:

Select text "_1111"

1. M-x iedit-mode`
2. `M-D` (to delete all find text **_1111**)
3. Input new text **_zero**

Here result.

1.aaa_zero_hello

2.aaa_2222_hello

3.aaa_zero_hello

4.aaa_4444_hello

5.aaa_zero_hello

6.aaa_5555_hello

7.aaa_zero_hello

8.aaa_zero_hello

...

100.aaa_zero_hello

OK.

But now I want to replace text ONLY from line "5.aaa_1111_hello" and to the end down. 
So as result I need to replace 98 lines.

The result must like this:

1.aaa_1111_hello

2.aaa_2222_hello

3.aaa_1111_hello

4.aaa_4444_hello

5.aaa_zero_hello

6.aaa_5555_hello

7.aaa**_zero**_hello

8.aaa**_zero**_hello

...

100.aaa**_zero**_hello

Is it possible by iedit?

Answer (score 2):

narrow the region you want to edit (https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Narrowing.html). Then use iedit as usual

You can also `iedit-toggle-selection` to toggle certain selections before text replacement.

You can navigate between selections. See code from `iedit-lib.el`,

```
(defvar iedit-lib-keymap
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    ;; Default key bindings
    (define-key map (kbd "TAB") 'iedit-next-occurrence)
    (define-key map (kbd "<tab>") 'iedit-next-occurrence)
    (define-key map (kbd "<S-tab>") 'iedit-prev-occurrence)
    (define-key map (kbd "<S-iso-lefttab>") 'iedit-prev-occurrence)
    (define-key map (kbd "<backtab>") 'iedit-prev-occurrence)
    (define-key map (kbd "C-'") 'iedit-toggle-unmatched-lines-visible)
    map)
```